# How to test DropWizard resource that returns a collection of objects?

Tags: java, testing, jersey, dropwizard

I'm building a service using DropWizard.  I have a endpoint that is expected to return a `List<Person>`

My unit tests looks like:

```
@Test
public void testGetListOfPeople() {

assertThat(
    resources.client().target("/people/?age=10").request().get(ArrayList<Person>.class))
    .containsAll(expectedList);
}
```

However, `request().get` won't allow me to specify a parameterized collection.

I've tried getting the response directly with:

```
r = resources.client().target("/people/?age=10").request().get()
```

but then its not clear how I convert `r` into a `List<Person>`

How can I update this test to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the Jersey client with collections can be a little frustrating. The solution is easy though, simply do the following:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;

resources.client().target("/people/?age=10").request()
    .get(new GenericType<List<Person>>(){});
```